# div alignment on different screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I achive this behaviour on different screens. (Grey rectangles are divs with some content). Assuming, picture 1 (left) is normal, wide screen; picture 2 (middle) is small (netbook or tablet) screen; picture 3 (right) is mobile screen.  I use bootstrap 3.
[image]

Comment: Why would you do that? From a UI/UX point of view.

Comment: second rectangle is the most important. thats why it is located in the middle. and for users with small screens (tablets and mobile) it should be on top.

Comment: This has been asked many times before on SO. Please take a look for duplicates before posting questions, and [read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: @ZimSystem, please, give me link to duplicate, because I dont even know how to google this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `pull push classes of bootstrap`.also learn about `col-*-offset-*` classes.

**To learn more check this site:**

[Twitter bootstrap official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/)

**This is an example how you can do it**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4" style="height: 100px; background-color: red;">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4  col-lg-pull-4" style="height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="height: 100px; background-color: green;">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad that I could help but try to learn about bootstrap grid system I am adding some resources in the answer..check those out

Comment: this code works before edit and it was posted earlier. @neophyte, please fix it (or I mark another answer as right)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [offset column](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) and [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) classes. Making sure to apply each at the appropriate screen/grid size.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

div[class^="col-"] > div {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-md-push-4">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note:*** The extra DIV in the column DIVs is for illustrative purposes. Do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-md-push-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4">3</div>
</div>
```